# Any changes (CSS, components, etc) causes my Next.js/React app to lose state. What's wrong?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Anytime I make changes in a CSS file or components, etc, my entire app loses state.

From what I've read, hot loading should be the default in Next.js.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: This is not a good question, there's no way we can help you without knowing your app or having an example code.

Comment: I realize that, I was just asking in case someone had experienced the same issue. I ended up switching to Gatsby because there were just too many problems with Next. Gatsby worked straight out of the box.